# Mongo DB Query that iterates over the Array

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I want to run a Mongo DB query in Mongo shell.
which runs for each elements of an array, where each element consists of  `participantId` and meal id.
The query does this:

```
mealPlanPairs = [
    {"participantId": "60647d142330a251a859c300", "_id": "640891c8184c7bb950b75407"},
    {"participantId": "6065885a5adde01b1ee8a85f", "_id": "640891ac184c7bb950b75406"}
];
// Loop through each pair and perform the update
mealPlanPairs.forEach(function(pair) {db.ParticipantDietMealPlanDetailsDTO.updateOne(
    {"participantId": pair.participantId},
    {$set: {"mealPlan": db.MasterMealPlanDTO.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(pair._id)}).mealPlan}}
);});
```

Now in shell I can not run this query, because the Mongo shell doesn't support this. So currently I am running this query for each elements by manually adding the ids.
How can I write a query which iterates over the array and does the same?

Currently I am doing it manually:

```
db.getCollection('PARTICIPANT_DIET_MEAL_PLAN_DETAILS_PLAN').updateMany(
    {"participantId": "5f42698f60bb57ecc2049f8f"}, 
    {$set: {"mealPlan": db.MASTER_MEAL_PLAN.findOne({"_id": "64088fa3184c7bb950b753f6"}).mealPlan}} 
)
```

Is there any way to do it in one Mongo DB query?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define the mealPlanPairs array
var mealPlanPairs = [
  {
    "participantId": "60647d142330a251a859c300",
    "_id": "640891c8184c7bb950b75407"
  },
  {
    "participantId": "6065885a5adde01b1ee8a85f",
    "_id": "640891ac184c7bb950b75406"
  }
];

// Loop through each pair and perform the update
mealPlanPairs.forEach(function(pair) {
  db.ParticipantDietMealPlanDetailsDTO.updateOne(
    { "participantId": pair.participantId },
    { $set: { "mealPlan": db.MasterMealPlanDTO.findOne({ "_id": ObjectId(pair._id) }).mealPlan } }
  );
});
```

- `mealPlanPairs` array defined
- used `forEach` to loop through the elements
- for each elt, call `updateOne` (updates the feild `mealPlan` in `ParticipantDietMealPlanDetailsDTO` collection with corresponding meal plan from `MasterMealPlanDTO` collection

PS. replace collection and field names with correct names from your DB